# Vega-Lite / Kibana : How can I make a table that shows calculations between aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite

I want to do a data table in kibana like the following:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pVzF.png)

That means, the 2 first columns are the sum of price and quantity and the 3rd column divides both sums to get a ratio.
Also I want this to be dynamic to changes in time range.

As far as I've seen getting the ratio is not possible in kibana, but I've noticed that there is a plugin were you can create Vega-Lite graphs in kibana.

I am new both in Vega-Lite and in kibana, so is there an example of code that creates a data table?
The [Vega-Lite site](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/aggregate.html) did not help me a lot...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could add a scripted field to calculate this ratio and then u can have the column you want :D
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html